# Ssh conection issue

Tags: networking, permissions, ssh, sshd, kerberos

I'm trying to establish a connection with Fermilab servers. For this I use both Kerberos protocol and ssh to connect my computer; however I only receive kerberos ticket and this message from terminal when entering `ssh -y (my username )@emphaticgpvm01.fnal.gov`. The message that is displayed on my terminal is the following.

```
The authenticity of host 'emphaticgpvm01.fnal.gov (IP)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:bxHRlFrCocX957QxVw7Tm91KEM9GIKRdfsjkNZ5Gi4U.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
(...)@emphaticgpvm01.fnal.gov: Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I am not sure if ssh/conf or ssh/sshd_confg files have to be modified.
Any advice on this is welcome, it is my first time trying this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the *key.pem*, *ip* and *ubuntu (username)* according to your ssh server:

```
chmod 600 key.pem
ip=34.219.106.143
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No -i key.pem ubuntu@$ip uptime
ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@$ip
```